# MassTransit - Running code when messages sent to error queue

Tags: masstransit

In MassTransit, how can I notify users that an error has occurred after the retry policy stops retrying? Can I run custom code when messages are sent to the error queue, maybe as some kind of middleware? I'm using the MassTransit 3.0.11 beta with RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing a request/response conversation, where a client is sending a request and the service is failing and moving the request to the error queue?

If so, you can handle the fault (which is sent back to the requestor when an exception occurs) as part of the request/response. Take a look at:

https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-RequestResponse

The request client will automatically wrap this and throw an exception if the service faults the request.

If you are doing something different, please include a code snippet.

Comment: I'm not using the request/response conversation. I just have an event that I'm publishing and consuming. An example of what I'm doing is [on github](https://github.com/josephdecock/MassTransitPubSubErrorHandler). A Request/Response conversation might actually be the right thing in my case, but I'm also interested in the pub/sub case.

Comment: What I'm trying to show in my example is a publisher and subscriber where the subscriber might experience transient errors. The subscriber is using a retry policy (for demo purposes, it doesn't try very hard) that eventually gives up if it can't perform its work. If that happens, I'd like to take some sort of action to notify the outside world of this failure - maybe send an email to the sysadmins, maybe publish a message to indicate that failure has occurred - but in general, I think it would be useful to be able to have a hook that runs when a message goes to the error queue.

Comment: In MT3 you can attach a consume observer that is called when a message faults. Of course this is per attempt and not on move. The Fault that's published is only when the message is moved. You could subscribe and consume this on a separate queue for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm having some trouble with the observers, but I will post a separate question to address that.